# Flip three coins

Tags: probability

Three friends (let's call them A,B,C) flip coins.
By getting 3 heads or 3 tails, they flip again until one of the coins is different from the other.

Denite Y:=number of rounds.

Find :

$1. P(Y=3)$

$2. P(Y\geq4)$

$3.$ $P$(The different coin is C)

***My solution:***

$P$(All coins are heads or tails)=$1\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$

$P$(one of the coins is different from the others)=$1-P$(all coins are heads or tails) $\implies 1-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$

$1. P(Y=3)=(1\cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2})^2\cdot(3\cdot \frac{1}{4})$

$2. P(Y\geq 4)=1-P(Y\leq 4)$

$P(Y\leq 4)=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{3}{4}+(\frac{1}{4})^2\cdot \frac{3}{4}+(\frac{1}{4})^3\cdot \frac{3}{4}=\frac{255}{256} \implies P(Y\geq 4)=1-\frac{255}{256}=\frac{1}{256}$

$3.$ I think the answer is $\{T,T,H\}+\{H,T,T\}=\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{4}$ but I am really not sure since I don't know how many rounds exist.

Is my solution correct?

I'd be grateful for feedback\help!

Comment: for 3. by symmetry the probability is $\frac{1}{3}$, the sample space is $\{HHT, TTH, HTH, THT, THH, HTT\}$

Comment: 1. and 2. are correct. Note that $Y$ follows a Geometric distribution with $p=1/4$.